# .htaccess 301 Redirect all content except for subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect `example.com` to `example2.com`, except for `example.com/wp-admin`

How do I redirect all pages on `example.com` to `example2.com` except for the subdirectory `example.com/wp-admin`?

I've tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^wp-admin/$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://example2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

but this does not work.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Presumably you have `RewriteEngine On` somewhere in your .htaccess file? Do you have any other directives in .htaccess? ...Is mod_rewrite / .htaccess enabled on your server etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in site root .htaccess of `example.com` site:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^wp-admin/ http://example2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Also make sure this rule is very first rule below `RewriteEngine On` line

Comment: No, `/wp-admin/` does not have a `.htaccess`.

Comment: I updated my question with example code I have tried.

Comment: Just keep these 3 lines as I have in my answer in your root .htaccess and also tell what error are you getting?

Comment: It is working now. Not sure what the difference was. Thank you.

Comment: @Steve Could have been a caching issue. 301 redirects are cached by the browser, so if you've made an erroneous redirect then you'll likely see the result of that error for a while... until the cache is cleared.